# Filtering capabilities of WPF datagrid

Tags: sql-server, wpf, filtering, wpftoolkit, wpfdatagrid

In a WPF application I need to implement convenient for user possibility of quick and easy search for particular records from a SQL Server database.

Please, could you share your expierience and opinion about filtering capabilities of WPF datagrid from a WPF Toolkit, comparing to third-party datagrids?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF DataGrid is an ItemsControl, so progmatically you can filter by anything you want - you just give it a Predicate to filter on - I'm sure that the built-in UI isn't as nice as 3rd-party Datagrid controls, but you can always write your own. It might be worth your time though to go with a 3rd party grid (I personally found Xceed's to be quite good).

Comment: Thank you, Paul! I think, I will download Xceed datagrid for evaluation.